# как улучшить читаемость кода js angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Добрый день, такой вопрос, как переписать эту длинную фигню в несколько строк, чтобы улучшить читаемость кода?

Логику я понимаю, но как именно разделить это, чтобы всё нормально работало, не знаю.
Или посоветуйте какие ресурсы и темы почитать.

```
<span class="fw-bold">
    {{ 
    (is_sum_dopolnitelno==0 && fields_dict['DOLG'].value!==0) ?  
    ( fields_dict['DOLG'].value>0 ? fields_dict['DOLG'].value : "0.00") : 
    getTotalSum(tns_total_sum) | fraction
    }}
         </span>
```

Comment: А разве нельзя это как функцию в скоуп занести в контроллере? А потом просто вывести этот скоуп ?

Comment: на мой взгляд этому коду место в `$scope` но никак не в представлении

Comment: @Bald а что значит занести в scope? в каком файле нужно эту функцию переписать? в .ts?

Comment: судя по комменту у Вас [tag:angular], на сколько я понял, да в компоненте создаете переменную/функцию в которой будет результат вычисления вашего тернарного оператора, и биндитесь к нему